# creating JSON in python from string not working

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

i am trying to create and display arrays from a string value.
First i try to create a JSON value from the string,
then i try to display key/values from it.

I get the error: Invalid syntax on last rule...
busy whole evening, but can't find dit out:(

Python3 code:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json

user = 'user'
pw = 'password'

login_url = 'http://www.xxxxxxx.nl/test/index.php'

data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'user': user, 'pw': pw})
data = data.encode('utf-8')
# adding charset parameter to the Content-Type header.
request = urllib.request.Request(login_url)
request.add_header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8")

f = urllib.request.urlopen(request, data)

## returning content from webpage: {"A":"aap","B":"noot","C":"mies"}

#json.JSONDecoder().decode(f)
#json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode(f)
#test = print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
test = f.read().decode('utf-8')
#print (test)
#test2 = json.JSONDecoder().decode(test)

test = '{"A":"aap","B":"noot","C":"mies"}'
dest = json.loads(test)
print dest['A']  ## <<< invalid syntax ??

#json.loads(test2)
```

Comment: Side note: You're not creating a "JSON object" from a string. There's no such thing as a JSON object. It's the _string_ that's JSON. You're creating a `dict` (not even some special kind of `dict`) from the JSON string representation of a dictionary/object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3.x - `print` is a function (ie: no longer a statement as in Python 2.x) - you need to use:

```
print(dest['A'])
```

instead of:

```
print dest['A']
```

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaarrrrrrrrrrgggg...spent hours on it!!! Life could be soooo easy:) Thank you!!!!!